Flyway migrate says schema is up to date to specific script
We have Applications like App A, App B, App C & App D. We have implemented multi tenancy and we are using flyway to create database when tenant is boarded, But flyway created A,C,D application schema and tables but for App B is showing Schema B is up to date. No migration necessary.
Folder structure
-DB
- Migrate
-A
AppA.sql
-B
AppB.sql
-C
AppC.sql
-D
AppD.sql
We want to create database of AppB along with tables

What command(s) are you running to apply the migrations?

Flyway fly = Flyway.configure()
.configuration(flyway.getConfiguration())
.schemas(tenant.getOrgName()+""+tenant.getTenantId()+""+applicationName)
.defaultSchema(tenant.getOrgName()+""+tenant.getTenantId()+""+applicationName)
.locations(location)
.load();
fly.migrate();
I have method inside that I have written this code
@DavidAtkinson

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
